# SAS: Parsing a string/character value looking for multiple delimiters

Tags: parsing, sas

I am trying to find a way to parse rather long strings of text. I want to extract a substring between certain words in the string. Below is an example of the kind of text I am looking at:

```
String1 = "Report failed: FailType: FailLevel, FailDate 12.01.2016. InstanceType (name_of_type) -9234as-df32f-2f2f Error : Error_message1. Error : Error_message2. Error : Error_message3." 
String2 = "Report failed: FailType: FailLevel, FailDate 12.01.2016. InstanceType (name_of_type) -zx3s-d2f-211 Error : Error_message1. Error : Error_message2."
```

I would like to parse the string and create columns looking something like this:

```
Obs# | ErrorType1      | ErrorType2      | ErrorType3
  1  | Error_message1  | Error_message2  | Error_message3  
  2  | Error_message1  | Error_message2  |
```

So different numbers of errors for each string.

I have updated my current progress with the problem based on the initial two comments below:

```
If _N_ = 1 Then Pattern = Prxparse("/ Error /");
Retain Pattern;
```

```
Position = prxmatch(Pattern, Strings);
Substring = substr(Strings, Position);
```

This does give me the entire substring after the first occurence of the word " Error " - the blank spaces are intentional. However, I fail to create a loop or search for all occurences of the string ' Error '. I had something like this in mind.

```
    if prxmatch(Pattern, Strings) then
    do;
        String1 = prxposn(Pattern, 1, Strings);
        String2 = prxposn(Pattern, 2, Strings);
    end;
```

But based on my results (String1 and String2 are empty), it is clear I lack understanding of the prxposn function. I just found the PRXNEXT function, and would like to give this a go. Not sure yet how to get only a single error message at a time.

Best regards!

Comment: Look at the SCAN() function.

Comment: Regex might be a good option here. Check into the `prxparse` and `prxposn` functions. You can use these to find specific strings and return the position in which they start and end.

Comment: The SCAN() function seems to require a very "stringent" setup of the strings to parse through, a criteria which my strings do not fit. Going with Regex may be a better way, I will try and look into it. I've updated my question above, if you think you'd be able to help me on my way.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `CALL PRXNEXT`, which iterates through matches.  `PRXPOSN` identifies capture buffers, meaning groups of `( )` - but doesn't match multiple matches to one capture buffer directly.

This should work:

```
data have;
String1 = 
"Report failed: FailType: FailLevel, FailDate 12.01.2016. InstanceType (name_of_type) -9234as-df32f-2f2f Error : Error_message1. Error : Error_message2. Error : Error_message3." ;
rx_err = prxparse ('/Error : (.*?)\./ios');

start = 1;
stop = length(String1);
do _i = 1 by 1 until (position le 0);
    CALL PRXNEXT( rx_err, start, stop, String1, position, length);  
    if position gt 0 then do;
        err_msg = substr(string1,position,length);
        put position= length= err_msg=;
    end;
end;

run;
```

It might be problematic to stop the match on `.` if that could be contained inside the error message, but if so you'll have to find a better way to stop it.

The regex works by using `(.*?)` to match all characters, but not greedily, so when it hits `\.` (period) it stops.

You could use `PRXPOSN` after `CALL PRXNEXT` if you wanted to, to only get the `()`, always having `1` be the value of the capture buffer, I believe.  So instead of the `err_msg` assignment, use:

```
err_msg = prxposn(rx_err,1,string1);
```